# What's wrong with my foreach array variable?

Tags: php, wordpress

Our site

```
http://religiousstudiesproject.com/
```

had some major downtime today that Dreamhost support traced back to caching problems stemming from two PHP errors in our custom Wordpress theme.

We're planning a site re-do this summer, but the current theme is 2+ years old and pre-dates me. Can someone who is familiar with PHP tell me whether I'm likely to be able to hotfix these errors without being a PHP coding ninja?

I'm not sure where to begin, so any advice is useful!

> PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/wp_7ts6w3/religiousstudiesproject.com/wp-content/themes/religious-studies/header.php on line 23
>
> PHP message: PHP Warning:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/wp_7ts6w3/religiousstudiesproject.com/wp-content/themes/religious-studies/functions.php on line 735

EDITS:

I followed the suggestion below to check out line 23. Looking in our theme I see the following:

```
20 // display metatags for authors where necessary
21  $current_post_id = get_queried_object_id();
22  $acfield = get_field('persons', $current_post_id);
23  foreach( $acfield as $post){
24      setup_postdata($post);
25      ?><meta name="author" content="<?php the_title() ?>" /><?php
26  }
27  wp_reset_postdata();
28  if(! $acfield){
29       if (is_single()){
30          global $post;
31          $author = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author);
32          echo "<meta name=\"author\" content=\"$author\">";
33      }
34  }
```

The foreach uses the variable $acfield which I know is supplied by the WP user during content creation as "persons". Does this mean the $acfield is the invalid data in the foreach loop, that is, something is wrong with that array's construction? That's line 22, right? So do we need define that as an array explicitly? This is where I start to get way out of my depth.

The second function seems to have something to do with a failsafe for OpenGraph images with Jetpack. So that's social media related, I think. Maybe a backup logo for a sharing icon? It's not from the images users have uploaded to the site. I can't find the folder it points to or the file it's trying to use. So I commented the whole function out. Nothing went boom, so I'll wait to see if I notice any missing images or additional errors.

Comment: Honestly, just start at `/home/wp_7ts6w3/religiousstudiesproject.com/wp-content/themes/religious-studies/header.php` line 23 and see what's going on there.

Comment: You should add the functions that contain those lines (not just the single lines) to your question, someone may be able to identify the issue from there.

Comment: Are you able to add the lines and maybe even the surrounding lines in question for each file? It sounds like the errors are pretty simple but more context is required that just the error message, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, folks. I've copied the surrounding code from the first error. The second error I commented out the code for since it looks like something we're not using. The first piece of code, however, is used on every piece of content on our site, so I want to be much more cautious about changing things!